# Nodejs and mysql duplicate issue

Tags: mysql, node.js, duplicates

I'm using the mysql module for nodejs, and my program is running multiple workers with the cluster package.

Each worker get some tweets and store them in the database, but each record has to be unique by the tweet_id.

Now, I can see that a lot of duplicate records are present in my database, even if I'm checking for duplicates before inserting.

So, did you ever experienced this ? Is there a solution ?

Comment: I think you need to provide some more code and examples to make it comprehensible

Answer (score 0):

Me a newbee but try to help.

As you have multiple workers

under default transaction isolation level

when worker A is writing to the db

worker B may have already wrote TWEET

but its invisible to A

one common solution is set a unique index to tweet_id column